# ¿how to query all items created in netsuite rest api?

Tags: netsuite

I am doing an integration with the Netsuite API and I am testing the resources such as invoices, clients and products in Postman. I can't find a URL that shows all products (items). Do you know how to access this?

in the user interface it can be easily seen in: Lists>Accounting>items

Comment: There are at least four different apis for netsuite:  suiteql / suite analytics; suitetalk (soap); suitetalk (rest); restlet.  Which of these are you using?

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering. The type of integration I am doing is API REST with SuiteTalk

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [suiteql rest endpoint](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_158394344595.html) to submit suiteql queries.

The query you will want to submit in the `q` is:

```
select id, itemid from item
```

You can find the entire list of queryable fields [in the analytics browser](https://www.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2020_1/analytics/record/item.html).